# In which situations is a US LPR and French citizen who was refused entry to Canada allowed to withdraw their application for admission to Canada?

Tags: canada, borders, denial-of-entry, us-residents, french-citizens

I read on https://www.canadaduientrylaw.com/denied-entry-to-canada.php ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220125054148/https://www.canadaduientrylaw.com/denied-entry-to-canada.php)):

> In many situations where a US citizen is refused entry at the Canadian border, the visitor is allowed to request permission from the CBSA to officially withdraw their application for admission to Canada. If this "withdrawal of admission" is granted by border agents, the individual will be permitted to return to the US without having to experience a formal removal proceeding.

In which situations is a US lawful permanent resident and French citizen who was refused entry to Canada allowed to withdraw their application for admission to Canada?

---

(To avoid some comments: I was not refused entry yet but my last entry was not smooth. I was threatened that I may be denied entry under the reason "Intention to Work Illegally" and interrogated+searched for 1h because of the presence of a computer monitor in my car's back seat, so I'm getting ready for my next entry to Canada as I'm not giving up on my monitors.)

Comment: Why do you want a computer monitor? And could you ship the monitor separately from you?

Comment: @DJClayworth just being able to read books on a decently large screen. Not worth shipping since I was staying over the weekend only.

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but an iPad Pro has a large high resolution screen and is not likely to trigger the "intention to work illegally" response. Of course it's Apple so it's expensive, but it could avoid this sort of trouble in the future.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks I have some iPads but they're smaller than a regular monitor and missing basic features eg https://superuser.com/q/1692900/116475 I use it to read in planes though sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The border agent will allow you to withdraw your request for admission if you request it, unless an inadmissibility report is being prepared or has been prepared.

The agent has certain discretion on whether to prepare a report and may inform you of the options before they do so. They will consider whether the objectives of Canadian immigration law can be best served by a report or voluntary withdrawal, with the following considerations (from [ENF 5 - Writing 44(1) Reports](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/resources/manuals/enf/enf05-eng.pdf))

> 9.1  Considerations  before  writing an  A44(1) report
>
> Keeping  in  mind  the  scope  of  discretion  related  to considerations  for  writing  an  A44(1)  report outlined in  section  8 of  these  guidelines,  the  following  non-exhaustive  factors  may  be considered  when  exercising  the  limited  discretion  under  A44(1)  with respect  to  foreign  nationals:
>
> - Has the  person  been  granted  protected  person  status  in Canada?  What  is  the  nature or category  of  the  inadmissibility?
> - Is  the  person  already  the  subject  of  a  removal  order?
> - Is  the  person  already  the  subject  of  a separate  inadmissibility  report  incorporating allegations  that  will  likely
>   result  in a  removal  order?
> - Is  the  officer  satisfied  that  the  person  is,  or  soon  will  be,  leaving  Canada  on their  own volition? And  in such  a case,
>   is  the  imposition  of  a  future  requirement  to obtain  an
>   authorization  to  return  warranted?
> - Is  there  a  record  of  the
>   person  having  previously  contravened  immigration  legislation?
> - In  the  case of  non-compliance,  was it  unintentional  or  excusable  for  a  valid reason?
> - Has the  person  now  been  fully  counselled  on  the  topic  of  their  inadmissibility? And  is  the officer  satisfied  that  the
>   person  now  understands  what  is  required  in  future  to  overcome
>   their  inadmissibility?
> - Is  there  any  reason  to  believe that,  after  having  previously  been  counselled  on  the  topic of  their  inadmissibility,  the
>   person  simply  chose  to  ignore  that  counselling?
> - Has the
>   person  been  cooperative?
> - Is  there  any  evidence  of  misrepresentation?
> - Has the  person  applied  for  restoration of  status,  and  does  the  person  appear
>   to be eligible?
> - Has a  temporary  resident  permit  been  authorized?
> - How long  has  the  person  been  in Canada?
> - In  minor  criminality  cases,  is  a decision  on  rehabilitation imminent  and  likely  to be favourable?

However, once a report is being prepared (not necessarily finished), the agent can no longer authorize a withdrawal, only the Minister or their delegate (certain supervisors) then has the discretion whether to use a formal removal proceeding or not with similar considerations based on the report the agent prepared.

The procedure applies to all foreign nationals (i.e. not citizens or permanent residents of Canada).

> **Withdrawing application**
>
> 42 (1) Subject to subsection (2), an officer who examines a foreign
> national who is seeking to enter Canada and who has indicated that
> they want to withdraw their application to enter Canada *shall* allow
> the foreign national to withdraw their application and leave Canada.
>
> **Exception — report**
>
> (2) If a report is being prepared or has been prepared under
> subsection 44(1) of the Act in respect of a foreign national who
> indicates that they want to withdraw their application to enter
> Canada, the officer shall not allow the foreign national to withdraw
> their application or leave Canada unless the Minister decides either
> not to make a removal order or not to refer the report to the
> Immigration Division for an admissibility hearing.
>
> **Obligation to confirm departure**
>
> (3) A foreign national who is allowed to withdraw their application to
> enter Canada must appear without delay before an officer at a port of
> entry to confirm their departure from Canada.
>
> [*Immigration and Refugee Protection Regulations*](https://laws.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-2002-227/FullText.html)

Comment: What would be interesting to know, is given the previous action of the OP, did the Canadian authorities keep notes on it and will that influence a future entry attempt?  It may be that a future attempt to do the same thing could trigger formal proceedings rather than the previously obtained warning.

Comment: @PeterM Notes should be expected if non-routine interrogation is carried out; then there may be consideration re: "Is there any reason to believe that, after having previously been counselled on the topic of their inadmissibility, the person simply chose to ignore that counselling?"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is specific to US citizens. According [to this site](https://www.duicanadaentry.com/uncategorized/legislative-change-on-withdrawing-an-application-for-entry-into-canada/), it's the same for any foreign citizen.

It also answers your question:

> With this amendment, the possibility to withdraw application to enter is conditional on what the Minister decides. Although there is no change to existing policy or practice as this was a technical amendment, the new wording provides more clarity pertaining to withdrawing an application at the Canadian border

Comment: Great, thanks for the information! I wonder how the Minister makes their decision (tossing a coin vs. some objective criteria and if so, which ones).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I suspect the "Minister" is in fact a delegated authority to some kind of mid-level bureaucrat. In the US that would be a regional CBP district Director, I'm guessing in Canada it would be something similar.

Comment: @littleadv That’s correct. It’s the immigration supervisor at the border post. You can confirm that by watching an episode of Border Patrol. The Minister doesn’t even hear about it, heck it doesn’t get to even his secretary’s desk. 

Comment: @AugustineofHippo in border patrol, do they explain how the immigration supervisor makes the decision?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It varies case by case. I’ve seen episodes where the supervisor exercised that discretion because the traveler was very polite, or had great persuasive skills etc. Ultimately it’s largely  out of your control and dependent on their mood, previous adherence to immigration rules etc.